# Docker installation on the Mac

Tags: macos, docker

```
macOS Mojave - 10.14.5
```

I installed the Docker desktop for the Mac, and as part of the installation, it asked me for my docker email address and password. I entered those and the installation was completed.

From a terminal command line, when I do:

```
docker --version
```

The response is:

```
Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962
```

However, when I try to do:

```
docker run hello-world
```

I get the following response:

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/hello-world/manifests/latest: unauthorized: incorrect username or password.
```

From terminal, I tried:

```
docker login
```

and entered my docker email address and password, I get the following response:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: unauthorized: incorrect username or password
```

I am certain that my email and password are correct, because I verified them for accessing hub.docker.com and they work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there an http proxy on your network?

Comment: maybe this https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/935 would help

Comment: The username worked. It was a little misleading, because when I did "docker login", it suggested my email address, and it must have picked it from the docker desktop install for the Mac. If you turn this into an answer, I will give you credit for it